# Is it possible to do USB-debugging on Android when Phone's USB port is already used?

Tags: android, android-studio, usb, dji-sdk

Problem: I'd like to run an app on my Phone from my laptop, via USB, using Android Studio, while my phone is physically connected to another USB device (a remote controller for a drone).

In this case, I have:

- My Laptop (MacBook running Android Studio Bumblebee)
- My Phone (Samsung Galaxy with Android 11)
- A controller for a DJI drone (which plugs directly into the Phone)

Problem is the phone obviously only has 1 USB port, so can't connect to both the laptop and the controller.

Question: Is it possible (with a USB hub or maybe connecting both phone and controller to computer?) to do usb debugging on phone from laptop while phone communicates via USB to controller?

Note: I have successfully connected laptop-to-phone with WIFI-debugging before, but the connection can be a bit slow and laggy so it would be nice if it was possible with USB.  Additionally I am not able to do this while my phone is working as the internet hotspot for the laptop (so I need to bring in yet another hotspot device).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only option you have is to use the dji bridge app on a second phone.
It also uses the wifi, so I doubt it will work better than wifi-adb.

Comment: Great suggestion - using the bridge app now with my second phone and it works well.  It does use WIFI, but just for the video/control transmission - the logs from running the app still come back over USB - so it doesn't have the lag, or the frequent disconnections that I get with WIFI debugging.  Note: I had to make sure mobile data was off on the second phone to get the right IP in order for bridge app to work.

Comment: Good to hear! Sometimes the bridge-app is very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an Android 11 phone, you can use "Pair device using Wifi". In this way you can run the app into your phone from your pc.

[image]

Comment: See question - I was asking this because there is a lag when debugging with wifi.